# NServiceBus not publishing any messages

Tags: c#, .net, messaging, nservicebus

I'm working with NSB (latest version), got to the stage where I configure it correctly and manage to publish messages onto the bus. Only problem is - I'm not getting any of them in my message queues. The event log is clean - nothing to help me diagnose the error.

Help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The description of your problem is pretty brief, but since you are not getting any error messages and you're using the word "publish", I am guessing that you have forgotten to subscribe to your message.

Services that want to receive a published message need to issue a call to `bus.Subscribe<SomeMessageType>` somewhere - possible in the `Run` method of a class that implements `IWantToRunAtStartup`.

Comment: I'm not using the NSB host. I'm just trying to run a console app that uses `Configure` and has a single `IMessageHandler`. Am I missing something?

Comment: Another possibility is that you forgot to `Configure....UnicastBus().LoadMessageHandlers()` - but it's pretty hard to diagnose without any code